# Errors when using SSW to downlaod GOES data

Tags: idl, solar

I installed the SSW from the official site, then I tried downloading GOES data by using SSW, with the OS of Windows 11. However, some errors were confronted. The following is what shown in the Command-Line Interface when I entered "goes" and selected time interval and clicked the "Plot" button.

```
IDL> goes
% Compiled module: SOCK_GOES.
% ASTROLIB: Astronomy Library system variables have been added
% DEVICELIB: Added system variable !BCOLOR
% DEVICELIB: Added system variable !ASPECT
% GOES::READ: Please wait. Searching for GOES/SDAC data...
% Structure type not defined: IDLNETURL2.
% Execution halted at: SOCK_HEAD         108 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\sockets\sock_head.pro
%                      HAVE_NETWORK      116 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\sockets\have_network.pro
%                      GOES_SERVER        64 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes_server.pro
%                      RD_GOES_SDAC      164 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\rd_goes_sdac.pro
%                      GOES::READ       1262 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__define.pro
%                      GOES::GETDATA     305 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__define.pro
%                      GOES::PREPARE_PLOT  824 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__define.pro
%                      GOES::PLOTMAN    1169 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__define.pro
%                      GOES::EVENT       249 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__gui.pro
%                      GOES_EVENT        117 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__gui.pro
%                      WIDGET_PROCESS_EVENTS
%                      IDLNETURL2__DEFINE  254 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\objects\idlneturl2__define.pro
%                      OBJ_NEW         
%                      SOCK_HEAD         108 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\sockets\sock_head.pro
%                      HAVE_NETWORK      116 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\sockets\have_network.pro
%                      GOES_SERVER        64 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes_server.pro
%                      RD_GOES_SDAC      164 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\rd_goes_sdac.pro
%                      GOES::READ       1262 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__define.pro
%                      GOES::GETDATA     305 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__define.pro
%                      GOES::PREPARE_PLOT  824 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__define.pro
%                      GOES::PLOTMAN    1169 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__define.pro
%                      GOES::EVENT       249 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__gui.pro
%                      GOES_EVENT        117 E:\SSW\ssw\gen\idl\synoptic\goes\goes__gui.pro
%                      WIDGET_PROCESS_EVENTS
%                      $MAIN$
```

I have uninstalled IDL and SSW, then reintalled them. I also tried modifing "SSW_INSTR" in sswidl.bat. But it didn't work, the errors exist.